# Could not load value into angular-bootstrap typeahead values with resources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a problem with `angular-ui typeahead` component. It does not show values populated by angular resources, however using `$http` works well. I suppose I missing some trick here with asycn call and correct population of returned values.

**Working code**

```
$scope.searchForContact = function(val) {
  return $http.get('/api/contacts/search', {
    params: {
    q: val
  }
}).then(function(response){
  return response.data.map(function(item){
    return item.name;
  });
});
```

};

**Not working code**

```
$scope.searchForContact = function(val) {
  return Contact.search({q: val}, function(response){
    return response.map(function(item){
      return item.name;
    });
  });
});

...

'use strict';

app.factory("Contact", function($resource, $http) {
var resource = $resource("/api/contacts/:id", { id: "@_id" },
{
  'create':  { method: 'POST' },
  'index':   { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
  'search':  { method: 'GET', isArray: true, url: '/api/contacts/search', params: true },
  'show':    { method: 'GET', isArray: false },
  'update':  { method: 'PUT' },
  'destroy': { method: 'DELETE' }
}
);

 return resource;
});
```

**Pug template code**

```
input.form-control(
  type='text'
  ng-model='asyncSelected'
  uib-typeahead='contact for contact in searchForContact($viewValue)'
  typeahead-loading='loadingLocations'
  typeahead-no-results='noResults'
)
i.glyphicon.glyphicon-refresh(ng-show='loadingLocations')
div(ng-show='noResults')
  i.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove
  |
  |No Results Found
```

Angular resources are working fine, including search endpoint - I just output on page result returned by the search endpoint. In both results should be just an array with string values. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `$http.get` and your `Contact.search` is that the first one returns a promise and the latter doesn't. Any `$resource` method will usually be resolved to the actual response. I'll show that with an example.

**Getting data with $http**

```
var httpResult = $http.get('http://some.url/someResource').then(function(response) {
    return response.map(function(item) { return item.name });
});
```

The `httpResult` object contains a promise, so we need to use `then` method to get the actual data. Moreover, the promise **will be** resolved to the mapped array, which is the expected result.

**Getting data with $resource**

```
var someResource = $resource('http://some.url/someResource');
var resourceResult = someResource.query(function(response) {
    return response.map(function(item) { return item.name });
});
```

The `resourceResult` **isn't** a promise here. It's a `$resource` object which will contain the actual data after the response comes from the server (in short, `resourceResult` will be the array of contacts - the original, not mapped, even though there is a map function). However, the $resource object contains a `$promise` property which is a promise similar to one returned by `$http.get`. It might be useful in this case.

---

**Solution**

I read in documentation that in order to make uib-typehead work properly, the `$scope.searchForContact` needs to return a promise. Instead of passing the callback function to `search`, I would simply chain it with the `$promise` from `$resource` object to make it work.

```
$scope.searchForContact = function(val) {
  return Contact.search({q: val}).$promise.then(function(response){
    return response.map(function(item){
      return item.name;
    });
  });
});
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! But I confused about the fact that $resources are waiting for whole returned result. I was supposing that network IO in any case in NodeJS will be async so promise should be returned in both cases (as far as I understand promise is created for such aim). Am I correct when saying that $resources seem to be sync call?

Comment: Ah, I think I wasn't clear about the $resources. They are async calls, of course, but they just don't return promise. The promise is resolved internally and its result is assigned to the final object as soon as the response comes from the server. I suppose that they did this to increase readabilty of angular code. Thanks to this we can write e.g. `model.persons = Person.query()` and this will work as expected. Async call will be sent to the server and as soon as the promise is resolved, response will be assigned to `model.persons`. Thanks to $watchers, view will automatically get updated.

Comment: If we want to do some actions just after the response comes from the server, we can either pass a callback function to the $resource action (as you did at the beginning) or use the $promise property (which is the internal promise) as in the answer. What we use depends on what we want to achieve. Often it's interchangeable, but in your case $promise was the choice.